# Printing out a number as integer (no decimals)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Please can any one help me with Python? When I run the following code I get an output of 1.0 for both `L_` AND `L_1`, but I want it to be just 1.

```
import math

d_ = 0          # My student number last digit
n_ = 10 + 0     # nth roots of unity

import math as m     # for real
import cmath as m    # for complex

# K_     [ number of the root]
K_ = 9
Root = m.exp((2 * K_ * m.pi * 1j) / n_)      # determine the nth root of unity by using exponential form
Root1 = math.cos((2 * K_ * m.pi / n_)) + 1j * math.sin((2 * K_ * m.pi / n_))   # determine the nth root of unity by using polar form
p_ = (Root) **  (n_)      # 10th power of Root
p_1 = (Root1) **  (n_)    # 10th power of Root1
L_ = (Root.real ** 2 + Root.imag ** 2)       # Test whether the point Root lies on unit circle
L_1 = (Root1.real ** 2 + Root1.imag ** 2)      # Test whether the point Root1 lies on unit circle

print  L_    
print  L_1
```

Comment: Do you think all those `_` make the code easier to read?

Answer (score 0):

```
print int(math.round(L_))
```

If you want less rounding you can use the optional second `round` parameter to specify a number of places. Don't leave it out completely though, otherwise 0.9999999 becomes 0.

If you'd rather that the value be an integer in the first place, do it at the assignment:

```
L_ = int(math.round((Root.real ** 2 + Root.imag ** 2), 6)
```

Comment: Actually I just want to get an output of 1 (integer), when print this code for complex numbers

L_ = (Root.real ** 2 + Root.imag ** 2)